# windows 10 : scikit learn updating for 0.22 version is so bad for anaconda

Tags: windows, anaconda

For windows 10 : scikit learn updating for 0.22 version 
is very bad for new  anaconda version Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe
takes more than 3 hours and still running 
is it only for me?
meantime it is what I have these messages

(base) C:\Users\sndr>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing Pro 7.1\bin

(base) C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing Pro 7.1\bin>wing.exe

(base) C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing Pro 7.1\bin>conda install scikit-learn=0.22
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining msgpack-python:   3%|█▌                                                   | 11/386 [00:00<00:00, 1575.35it/s]\Examining scikit-learn:  16%|████████▌                                              | 60/386 [00:00<00:00, 1718.84it/-
Comparing specs that have this dependency:   0%|                                                 | 0/3 [00:00

Comment: It really shouldn't be: the versions in `win-64/anaconda-2019.10-py37` already satisfy the dependencies of `scikit-learn=0.22=py37h6288b17_0`. Is this a completely fresh install of Anaconda? Could you try `conda install scikit-learn=0.22=py37h6288b17_0` instead? One possibility is that there is some other package that has a scikit-learn dependency (e.g., constraining to <0.22) and Conda is trying to find a replacement.

Comment: Is this a completely fresh install of Anaconda? yes as I wrote file Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe was installed which was downloaded from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ yesterday. This command (base) C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing Pro 7.1\bin>conda install scikit-learn=0.22 still running from yesterday   so it takes more than 12 hours. Will stop installation  try this conda install scikit-learn=0.22=py37h6288b17_0. It really shouldn't be: the versions in win-64/anaconda-2019.10-py37 already satisfy the dependencies of scikit-learn=0.22=py37h6288b17_0 - actually it is not

Comment: same problem base) C:\Users\sndr>conda install scikit-learn=0.22=py37h6288b17_0
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the scikit-learn.

```
conda remove scikit-learn
```

It updated few packages and removed one.

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.22
```

scikit-learn 0.22.1 was installed. But few packages got removed like pandas and matplotlid. I had unistall them again.

I don't know what was causing this issue. But it got solved after reinstalling the scikit-learn.